# Handling Orientation Change for iOS in Titanium Studio?

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-mobile

I've read the docs and have the code below but am obviously missing something.

```
    Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function (ev) {
      if (Ti.Gesture.isLandscape(ev.orientation)) {
        // Update your UI for landscape orientation
      } else {
        // Update your UI for portrait orientation
      }
    });
```

What am I supposed to be doing to update my UI as mentioned in the comments above?  I've got a simple TabGroup, with WebViews inside.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to have orentaion change to your window

use this

```
var window = Ti.UI.createWindow({
   orientationModes: [
      Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT,
      Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT,
      Ti.UI.PORTRAIT,
      Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT
     ]
```

});

this code tells that your window now have all oreintaions

now you need to make some ui changes say in portaint you have width :320 and height 480

you need know when the change was happened. soo oreintchange event is used

```
Ti.Gesture.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(e) {
      Titanium.API.info('Orientation changed to '+e.orientation);
        if(e.orientaion=="Ti.UI.PORTRAIT")
        {

                width:320,height:480
        }
    else{

  width:480,height:320

 }



 });
```

Comment: I had set the allowed orientation modes in  tiapp.xml and didn't realize we had to manually shift the window dimensions.  That seems like something that would be handled for any orientations that are supported, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[KitchenSink  Get Orientations](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/common/phone/orientation.js)

look at this example .it will be helpful

Comment: Up-voting for pointing out the obvious I should have checked first.  Thanks!